# Phonegap app performance on Nexsus vs Samsung

Tags: html, phonegap-build, samsung-mobile, construct-2

I'm developing a mobile game for kids in HTML5 using Construct 2 as game engine and Phonegap build to compile the game. I test my game on Nexus 4, 5, and 9 devices, on HTC and on Samsung Galaxy S4 and Samsung Note 3. On the Nexuses and on the HTC my game runs well, but on the Samsung devices my game stuck. What can be difference between the devices?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: Many differences. 
Here are some helpful articles.

*Android Fragmentation Visualized* 
http://opensignal.com/reports/2014/android-fragmentation/

*How Carriers and Manufacturers Make Your Android Phone’s Software Worse* 
http://www.howtogeek.com/163558/how-carriers-and-manufacturers-make-your-android-phones-software-worse/

*How fragmentation affects the Android ecosystem* 
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-fragmentation-affects-the-android-ecosystem/